# Difference between Haskell ListT, LogicT and ChoiceT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

What is the difference between these three monad transformers?

- [ListT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-List.html#t%3aListT)
- [LogicT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/logict/0.5.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Logic.html#t%3aLogicT)
- [ChoiceT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/contstuff/1.2.6/doc/html/Control-ContStuff-Trans.html#t%3aChoiceT)

Comment: You should probably link to the docs for the types you're referring to and make your question more specific.

Comment: Please be more specific -- do you mean just the `MonadTrans` instance for these types, or their behavior in general?

Comment: @Don Stewart: in general.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, first of all `ListT` is not a true monad transformer.  It disobeys the associativity law for certain underlying monads.  It is also pretty slow, as is the monadic interface to lists in general.  It is built on actual lists internally.

`LogicT` is probably the best choice for list-like monad transformers.  It not only implements a proper monad transformer, but also some very useful combinators for *fair* list products.

`ChoiceT` is my own work.  It is basically just a CPSed version of `LogicT` and is inspired by both `LogicT` and the `ChoiceT` from *monadLib*.  It's very fast, often outperforming (non-transformed) lists, but the types may be scary and you are bound to the result type, which may be in your way sometimes.

Conclusion:  If you're serious, use `LogicT`.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that `runLogicT` and `runChoiceT` are folds?

Comment: @Tinctorius: Both `LogicT` and `ChoiceT` encode lists as folds of some sort anyway, and as usual the "run" functions just unwrap that. Folds are already similar to a CPS'd list, and `ChoiceT` adds an extra layer of proper CPS on top of that, which is why it has a type signature only a mother could love. ;]

Comment: Would you mind describing this "proper CPS" in a little more detail or giving a reference? I originally thought that logictt was already basically a cpd's version of ListT done right